# download users profile pics from Facebook: AsyncTask or HandlerThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handlerthread

I've a list of urls. Each url holds a differenct facebook user's profile pic.

I would like to download these pics and display them on the UI thread (on the screen).

I used new AsyncTask for each image and the images are displayed one by one.

**doInBackground** (background thread) returns the Bitmap:

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imgUrl).openStream();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

**onPostExecute** (UI thread) will set the image bitmap for my members

1. Is it the correct way to download the pics or I need to use Handlers?
2. AsyncTask is chosen when users want to make changes on the UI while Handler is used to communicate between any 2 threads by messages. Is there any special difference? because it seems that I could use both attitudes.

Comment: Why don't you use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/README.md) or other community supported libraries like Picasso?

Comment: I didn't read about it but someone in stackoverflow suggested asynctask to some user and it looked like it's the correct way so I want to know the differences between the attitudes

Comment: @Rohan Bhatia has pointed out correctly the differences, but I would suggest also in the case of images to use community libraries because they're more easy to implement and in fact, they're based on AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async Task is often the simplest way to work on a seperate thread than UI thread, but its not always the best one.

**My rule of thumb would be:**

If you are doing something isolated related to UI, for example downloading data to present in a list, go ahead and use AsyncTask.

If you are doing multiple repeated tasks, for example downloading multiple images which are to be displayed in ImageViews (like downloading thumbnails) upon download, use a task queue with Handler.

**EDIT:**

As @Thecave3 pointed out it is best to let the image loading libraries do the loading for you. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) are suitable choices. They even provide download and error placeholders as optional features.